# Installing Memgraph on Windows

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I was wondering what would be the best way to install Memgraph on Windows? Docker seems to be an option, but is there a different/easier way?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I can install it on Windows 10 using the Windows subsystem for Linux. I just need to set the subsystem first. After that just run the following command:

```
dpkg -i /path/to/memgraph_<version>.deb
```

[Here](https://memgraph.com/blog/how-to-install-memgraph-and-memgraph-lab-on-windows-1-0/) I found a step-by-step tutorial.